# Laravel 7: How to add numeric value with date?

Tags: laravel, datetime-format, laravel-7, php-carbon

I'm calculating the difference between two dates. I want to make addition/subtraction a numeric/decimal value with the date.

```
Example: 

Start = 2022-06-28 
end = 2022-06-29 


total= (start - 0.5) - ( end - 0)
     = 1.5
or 
total= (start - 0) - ( end - 0)
     = 2
or 
total= (start - 0.5) - ( end - 0.5)
     = 1
```

Code:

```
$second_half = $request->session_1; // value = 0.5
$first_half = $request->session_2; // value = 0.5
$start = Carbon::parse($request->start_date); // value (YYYY-MM-DD) = 2022-06-28
$end = Carbon::parse($request->end_date); // value (YYYY-MM-DD) = 2022-06-29
$total_days = $end->diff($start); // this result can be decimal like 1.5
```

Actually, I want to divide the full day into two-part. First half and second half. So when I calculating the difference between two dates it should calculate the full day by (first half + second half). If I select 2022-06-28 first half and 2022-06-29 second half, it will count 2 days. If I select 2022-06-28 first half and 2022-06-29 first half, it will count 1.5 days.

I hope my concept is clear to you. How can I make this calculation?

Comment: I suppose that you know which half do a user choose?

Comment: Yes.  user will select the first and second half for both start and end dates.

Comment: I'm storing the total_days result as a numeric value. So for first and second half it should calculate the date with +- 0.5 . It shouldn't calculate with time frame. Suppose I want to take leave from today and tomorrow. But tomorrow I will be at office after first half ( this half is calculating only the office time, not 24 hours,). So I will take leave from today first half to tomorrow first half. So the total_days will be 1.5 days. How can I get this 1.5 days value?

Comment: `$first_half` & `$second_half` can be 0 or can be missing from request?

Comment: No, every half holds 0.5 value. But I need to calculate these half depends on condition. Suppose I select today first half to tomorrow second half. For this I don't think I have to calculate. Because it's already full day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test please the followind code?

```php
    $startDate = '2022-06-28';
    $endDate = '2022-06-29';
    $second_half = 0.5;
    $first_half = 0.5;

    $start = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($startDate);
    $end = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($endDate);
    $total_days = (float) $end->diff($start)->days;

    if($first_half) {
        $total_days += $first_half;
    }
    if ($second_half) {
        $total_days += $second_half;
    }
    
    $total_days = preg_replace('/\\.$/','.0',rtrim($total_days,'0'));
    
// dd($total_days);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$second_half = $request->session_1; // value = 0.5
$first_half = $request->session_2; // value = 0.5
$start = Carbon::parse($request->start_date . ($first_half ? ' 12:00' : ' 00:00'));
$end = $second_half
    ? Carbon::parse($request->end_date . ' 12:00')
    : Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->addDay();
$total_days = $end->floatDiffInDays($start);
```

Comment: I'm storing the total_days result as a numeric value. So for first and second half it should calculate the date with `+- 0.5` . It shouldn't calculate with time frame. 
Suppose I want to take leave from today and tomorrow. But tomorrow I will be at office after first half ( this half is calculating only the office time, not 24 hours,). So I will take leave from today first half to tomorrow first half. So the total_days will be 1.5 days. How can I get this 1.5 days value?

Comment: `$start = Carbon::parse($request->start_date) - 0.5 ;`
`$end = Carbon::parse($request->end_date) -0.5 ;`

How can I make this workable? If I get this solution, I can manage the rest.

Comment: The approach of KyleK is also useful in some situations. ;)